# Kotlin equivalent to swift if let? - for class variables?

Tags: kotlin

I'm aware of `.let {}` but the evaluated expression is inside a lambda expression which doesn't work too nice if you need to return something inside a method.

**Example problematic code**

```
fun method(): Int {
  if (anyObject != null) {
    val calculatedValue = anObject!!.awesome()
    val magicTrick = calculatedValue + randomMethodName()

    return magicTrick
  } 
  return false
}
```

**Is there a better way than this**

```
fun method(): Int {
  val tempObject = anObject
  if (tempObject != null {
    val calculatedValue = tempObject.awesome()
    val magicTrick = calculatedValue + randomMethodName()

    return magicTrick
  } else {
    return false
  }
}
```

**Swift equivalent**

```
fun method(): Int {
  if let tempObject = anObject {
    let calculatedValue = tempObject.awesome()
    let magicTrick = calculatedValue + randomMethodName()

    return magicTrick
  } else {
    return false
  }
}
```

Comment: The value returned by the lambda passed to `let` is returned by the `let` function itself. It should work nicely to return something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, your swift code can be even simpler without `if let`

```
func method() -> Boolean { return anObject?.someBoolean ?? false }
```

If this is the actual method you want to implement, the kotlin equivalent is:

```
fun method() : Boolean = anObject?.someBoolean ?: false
```

If you need to compute the boolean from the property of the optional:

```
fun method() : Boolean = anObject?.someProperty?.let{functionThatReturnBoolean(it)} ?: false
```

`.let{}` returns the last line within its body, which can be useful in many cases.

`someThing?.let{}` will return `null` if `someThing` is `null` due to optional chaining.

`?:` is the default value operator equivalent to `??` in swift, which returns the value on rhs when its lhs is `null`.

Comment: I'll try to update the example with something more complex in order to illustrate my issue.

Comment: I don't know any `+` operation which would return Boolean as your updated code means... but I assume you would do something on the property to return a Boolean, which is equivalent to `functionThatReturnBoolean(it)` in my updated answer.

Comment: I guess the fact that `.let{}` returns its last line is what you want to know.

Comment: Hmm yes I'll just experiment with that information :)

Comment: So I had gotten into my head that the let would be evaluated as a lambda expression without a return. I was wrong. Thanks for the help.